# Elasticsearch Java Api: set a field as _id

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to ask if the unique field `_id` be assigned by certain field within document. I see with Rest, it can achieve by `path`:

```
{
  "tweet": {
    "_id": {
      "path": "post_id"
    }
  }
}
```

But if I want to do it with java API, is there any way to achieve it?

```
Map<String, Object> MapA= new HashMap<String, Object>();
MapA=MapProcessor(MapA);

client.prepareIndex("index","type").setSource(MapA).execute().actionGet();
```

How could I modify my code to assign certain field in Map to become `_id` of this type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just provide id while indexing, like this

```
Map<String, Object> MapA= new HashMap<String, Object>();
MapA=MapProcessor(MapA);

client.prepareIndex("index","type",MapA.get("post_id")).setSource(MapA).execute().actionGet();
```

If you don't want to do this, add this as mapping then.

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "_id" : {
            "path" : "post_id"
        }
    }
}
```

if you add post_id field to elasticsearch, then it will become "_id" too .

Comment: Thank you! btw, do you know if its there a way to index mulitiple fields in MapA?

Comment: Can you ask it as separate question with example?? If the answer solved your problem, why not accept it??

Comment: I will open a new post to ask that~ Thanks for your help!